# Can I access album's cover art with Musixmatch API?

Tags: api, cover, albumart, musixmatch

In the Musixmatch API documentation it is said

> Get an album from our database: name, release_date, release_type,
> **cover art**.

In the JSON response example there is also "album_coverart_100x100",
but when I'm making an API call, in the response there is no image availible.

Answer (score 1):

You can get an album art field as the response of `album.get`, but not from `track.search`. So if you're trying to show the album art for a result that the user has searched for, you might want to make another api call to `album.get` and get the value of the key `album_coverart_100x100` for the url of the album art.